# How to get relation between two facebook userid's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, c#-4.0

I want to Scan Facebook friends list and find potential relationship between Facebook user and potential friend.After login I will give a user id then the system should find out the whether he is a friend any of my friend or friend's friend.Loop friend’s friend list up to 3 levels. If there are matches present data in hierarchical format.My application was in Asp.net mvc3. Can you please suggest me a solution .

Answer (score 0):

You need **user_relationships** permission for your needs , Refer this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/

Comment: actually i want to list the level of users juat like one in linkedin.. that is first level or second level or third level...